# IE won't load JSON and tries to download root file! (I'm following a tutorial which works on all other browsers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer, jsonp

I'm following a tutorial using $.ajax, jsonp, and the twitter API.

The example works on all browsers except for IE, unfortunately. And I when I try to load the twitter URL (http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bowery) into an IE browser, IE attempts to *download* the file.

I tried to fix this by adding  **contentType: 'text/plain',** under **dataType: 'jsonp',**, as well as  **contentType: 'text/html'**, and  **contentType: 'text/javascript'**, but none of those variations have worked. Has anyone solved this jsonp + IE + $.ajax issue before?

Tutorial code on github: https://github.com/troyth/webassite.com/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial4/index.html.

Javascript:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('doc ready!');

      var search_term = {
        q: 'harrypotter'
      };
      search(search_term);
    });

  function search(search_term) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?' + $.param(search_term),
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        for (item in data['results']) {
          $('#tweets').append(
            '<li>' + data['results'][item]['text'] + '</li>');
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

HTML:

```
    <ol id="tweets"></ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems there is an issue with the loop and accessing the object, this works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var search_term = {
        q: 'harrypotter'
    };
    search(search_term);
});

function search(search_term) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
        data: search_term,
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data['results'], function (k, v) {
            $('#tweets').append('<li>' + v.text + '</li>');
        });
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CzhGF/2/)

Comment: I tried this, and the tweets still wouldn't load for me in IE. :/

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, though.